# Dbcontext Inheritance error while attempting to activate repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My application has two databases: MainDbContext which inherits from DbContext and IdentifiedDbContext which inherits from MainDbContext.

MainDbContext uses base classes like EntityBase with Id, createdAt, updatedAt. IdentifiedDbContext uses IdentifiedEntityBase classes that inherit from EntityBase with properties CreatorId, OwnerId.

My application also has a Repository, and IdentifiedRepository which inherits from Repository.

Code looks like this:

```
public class BeehouseContext:DbContext
{
    public BeehouseContext(DbContextOptions<BeehouseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        // -- Construtor
    }

    protected BeehouseContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
    {
        // -- Construtor fix
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        #region EntityBase
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Beehouse.Framework.Domain.EntityBase>();
        #endregion
    }
}

{

    public BeehouseIdentityContext(DbContextOptions<BeehouseIdentityContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        // -- Construtor
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        #region EntityBase
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Beehouse.Framework.Identity.Domain.IdentifiedEntity>();
        #endregion
    }
}
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    protected readonly BeehouseContext Context;

    public Repository(BeehouseContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    private DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

    protected virtual DbSet<TEntity> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entities is null)
            {
                _entities = Context.Set<TEntity>();
            }
            return _entities;
        }
        }
// Other methods
    }
public class IdentifiedRepository<TEntity>:Repository<TEntity>, IIdentifiedRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:IdentifiedEntity
{
    protected readonly string UserId; // as Dealer
    protected readonly string CreatorId; // as Retailer
    protected readonly string CreatorAlias;

    public IdentifiedRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, BeehouseIdentityContext context):base(context)
    {
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("sub") == null) return;
        CreatorId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("sub").Value;
        CreatorAlias = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(SubscriptionClaimTypes.ProfileName).Value;
        UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(SubscriptionClaimTypes.DealerUserId).Value;
    }
```

In dependency injection I can create an instance of `IdentifiedRepository`, but in some cases I need to instantiate the Repository only, but I can't. The following error is thrown:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Beehouse.Framework.Identity.Data.BeehouseIdentityContext]'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'Beehouse.Framework.Identity.Data.BeehouseIdentityContext'.

I've tried to edit constructors like:

```
BeehouseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
BeehouseIdentityContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
```

But this doesn't work either.

My dependency injection looks like this and doesn't work:

```
    // Database
services.AddDbContext<IdentityServerContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connstring"))); 
services.AddTransient(typeof(BeehouseContext), typeof(BeehouseIdentityContext));
```

I also tried to add `DbContext` like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<IdentityServerContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("auxiliarc-local")));
        services.AddDbContext<BeehouseContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("auxiliarc-local")));
```

But that fails too with the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'Plan' because
>   this type is not included in the model for the context.

Plan are in namespace and Project Identified, but inherits from EntityBase only.

Can somebody help-me? Thanks.

Comment: Quick fix: EF Core does not need to be hidden behind a Repository. You are creating both a maintenance nightmare and gaining absolutely nothing out of that. Solution: remove those repositories and use EF as it is intended to be used

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: One of the benefits of hiding it behind a repository is abstracting out the data store, although I do agree with you that in practice, it almost never works out that way.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: that's disputable, not a fix but a subjective recommendation then.

Comment: @JuanR Like if that was a real concern... Just switch `UseSqlServer` for `UseInMemoryDatabase` and done

Comment: Also, the repository returns `DbSet<TEntity>` so it needs EF Core to work. That is utterly useless

Comment: Whether his repository is well designed or not is another story. From a Unit Testing perspective, abstracting the data store is almost always a good idea too.

Comment: Repositories contains usual methods like update, insert, delete. In method "insert" i have procedures like set de creation date and previne the entity to be saved with UserId diferente of the loged-in user id. My architeture is: API -> Service -> Repository -> Database. Suposes that i remove repository layer. So I need to call database direct from service?

Comment: `So I need to call database direct from service?` Correct. Use the provided EF types directly in your service(s). The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. You are adding nothing of value by wrapping these, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use.

Comment: @JuanR I get this concept from NopCommerce Project. Its return DbSet<TEntity> to Service, and service use it to construct queries

Comment: @Igor I'll try it. Thanks. If somebody have a documentation about this, please send it to me.

Comment: @RaulMedeiros: If you are using it in this manner, then I have to agree with others that it negates the need for a repository abstraction in the middle. The alternative for true abstraction would be to use interfaces (e.g. `IEnumerable<TEntity>`) instead. I am not a big fan of NopCommerce, by the way. I played with it several years ago and back then, the code was convoluted and a nightmare to maintain (which reflects what others have mentioned here, by the way).

Comment: *I get this concept from NopCommerce Project* - Wow, no wonder why you are confused. NopCommerce is a good example of a bad example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injector is looking to create an instance of type `BeehouseIdentityContext`.

The constructor requires an object of type `DbContextOptions`. The injector cannot instantiate this type for the activation of `BeehouseIdentityContext` so it throws an error.

Either tell the injector how to create instances of type `DbContextOptions` or create a constructor that uses defaults and does not need this type.

Comment: How I tell the injector to create specific type?

Comment: The documentation states that you can use a `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to create instances of this class. Add a binding to your injection like you do for your other services and use an overload that allows you to provide the implementation for the activation, then use the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` in there.